# XStream - using different converters for the same field type

Tags: java, xstream

I have several kinds of messages, where every message type has the same "envelope" and header, but different "body".

For instance, I may have messages like:

```
<doc>
    <header send_date="2013-06-06T15:00:00" />
    <body>
        <person>
            <start_time>2013-06-10T10:00:00</start_time>
        </person>
    <body>
</doc>


<doc>
    <header send_date="2013-06-06T15:03:00" />
    <body>
        <end_of_the_world_prediction time="2015-06-10T10:00:00" />
    <body>
</doc>
```

Here's the challenge. `send_date` in `header` needs to be serialized using local time zone. However, all dates in `body` need to be serialized in another time zone (that may be different for each message, but is known to the code kicking off XStream).

How can I achieve this?

There are quite a few kinds of those messages and they can be pretty big, so I'm not willing to manually craft a custom `Converter` for each.